# Google service account doesn't see project ID

Tags: authentication, google-compute-engine, gcloud

I'm trying to authorize using gcloud service account:

```
gcloud auth \
  activate-service-account "${GC_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}" \
  --key-file <filename> \
  --project <project name>
```

it authorizes successfully, but can't seem to find the project showing the following error for all commands:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.copy-files) Could not fetch instance:
 - The resource 'projects/<project name>' was not found
```

p.s. it works fine with `gcloud auth login`

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this. It looks like a bug. We'll investigate.

Comment: Can you user other commands, such as `gcloud compute instances list`?

Comment: @ZacharyNewman nope, same error

Comment: Does `gcloud version` show 0.9.71? If so, please run `export CLOUDSDK_COMPONENT_MANAGER_FIXED_SDK_VERSION=0.9.70 && gcloud components update` and try again. Do you still see the issue?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure of the project ID? Note that it is different from the project name. (Sorry for the spray of questions; I was wrong about being able to reproduce earlier and it's hard to diagnose remotely).

Comment: I'm absolutely sure of project ID :) it used to work a few days ago, then stopped working then worked again. Not sure why all the flakiness.

Comment: version: Google Cloud SDK 0.9.70

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84739/discussion-between-zachary-newman-and-grozz).

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of anyone else who encounters this problem: it looks like a transient issue. Please generate a new service account and try again.

If that doesn't work, please comment on this answer.